# Access violation error while memset

Tags: c++11, pointers, access-violation

```
 typedef struct
 {
   long nIndex;                     // object index
   TCHAR    path[3 * MAX_TEXT_FIELD_SIZE];

  }structItems;

void method1(LPCTSTR pInput, LPTSTR pOutput, size_t iSizeOfOutput)
{
  size_t        iLength = 0;

  iLength = _tcslen(pInput);
  if (iLength > iSizeOfOutput + sizeof(TCHAR))
    iLength = iSizeOfOutput - sizeof(TCHAR);

  memset(pOutput, 0, iSizeOfOutput); // Access violation error
}

void main() 
{
   CString csSysPath = _T("fghjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj");
   structItems *pIndexSyspath = nullptr;
   pIndexSyspath = (structItems *)calloc(1, sizeof(structItems) * 15555555); //If i put size as 1555555 then it works well
   method1(csSysPath, pIndexSyspath[0].path, (sizeof(TCHAR) * (3 *     MAX_TEXT_FIELD_SIZE)));
}
```

This is a sample code which cause the crash.

- In the above code if the size we put 1555555 then it works well (I randomly decreased size by a digit).
- This is a 32 bit application running on 64 Bit Win OS on 16GB RAM

I kindly request some one to help me understand the reason for failure and relation between calloc - size - memset.

Comment: Have you checked that the allocation *worked*, that `calloc` didn't return a null pointer?

Comment: And why are you using `typedef` and `calloc` if you're programming in C++?

Comment: More to the point, why are you using `memset` to set the memory to zero? Don't you know that [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/calloc) already does that? Using `calloc` is equivalent to `malloc` followed by  `memset`.

Comment: Lastly, what is `MAX_TEXT_FIELD_SIZE`? Is it a macro? What is it defined as? Without a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can really only guess.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Thanks for prompt response. Just now checked. It is returning null pointer for crash case.

Comment: 'typedef and calloc'  code seems coming from ages & I did not implemented it,  I am analyzing some crash issue

Comment: - Method 1 is an API which can't be modified. So, if calling function  use malloc,  'nIndex' feild can't be initialized and path 'feild' is only initialised using memset in method1. Hence, calloc was used to initialise both the fields. MAX_TEXT_FIELD_SIZE is a macro of size 255

Comment: Since we can't calculate how much memory you attempt to allocate, you have to remember that is has to be *contiguous*. If it's not possible to map such a large area as a contiguous chunk into your program then the allocation will fail.

Comment: This is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable

Comment: By the way, 15555555 is actually a number which will calculated dynamically from other means. For the sake of example I have shown the hard coded value. Could work around be suggested for the same??

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing definitions of `TCHAR`,  `LPCTSTR` and `CString` - did you omit one or more `#include` lines? Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: winnt.h  & afxstr.h are headers. typedef WCHAR TCHAR, *PTCHAR; typedef LPCWSTR PCTSTR, LPCTSTR; typedef ATL::CStringT< TCHAR, StrTraitMFC_DLL< TCHAR > > CString; This is an MVC project. Hence there headers are preincluded

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct
{
    long nIndex;  // 4 bytes on Windows
    TCHAR    path[3 * MAX_TEXT_FIELD_SIZE]; // 1 * 3 * 255 bytes for non-unicode
} structItems;
```

Supposing non unicode, `TCHAR` is 1byte, `MAX_TEXT_FIELD_SIZE` is 255, so `sizeof(structItems)` is `255*3 + 4`, which is `769` bytes for a struct. Now, you want to allocate `sizeof(structItems) * 15555555`, which is more than 11GiB. How could that fit into 2GiB available to 32-bit process.